# LibCurl how to catch both 400, not as a part of CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR error

Tags: c++, libcurl

In C++ Libcurl library, distinguish http error 400 from 404?
I have following code. I'm catching `>=400` using `CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR` but I want to catch error `400` separately before `CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR` case. Is there a way to do that?

```
curlCode = curl_easy_perform(request);
.....
switch(curlCode)
{
   case CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR:

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`curl_easy_getinfo`](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html) allows you to get the response code.

```
long responseCode;
curlCode = curl_easy_perform(request);
curl_easy_getinfo(request, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &responseCode);
if (responseCode == 400) {
    // handle error 400
} else {
    switch (curlCode) {
        ...
    }
}
```